# Why the maximum number of points of tangency between a line and a generic surface is four?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This proposition comes from the book ***Catastrophe theory***.
[image]

I don't understand why it's four. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: There are a number of books with the same title. Please give the author(s).

Comment: @JeanMarie : The author is Vladimir I. Arnol'd. Here is the link [link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-58124-3)

Comment: Could you supply more context (for example, what is a "generic surface")? As I understand this is false. For example, take the curve $t \mapsto (kt, sin(kt))$ and the line $(x,1)$. by setting $k$ to be large enough we can make the curve and the line be tangent to each other as much as we like.

Comment: @Alexey : I didn't find the definition of _generic surface_. But I guess what the author wants to say is that by a small perturbation, a line can only be tangent to at most 2 points with the curve. For example, (kt,sin(kt)-kt*kt/N), where N is a sufficiently large number.

Comment: @Alexey : Here is some ideas. The tangent lines between two spheres form a cone surface. If this cone surface intersects a third sphere, then there are some lines be tangent to all three spheres. And the number of points of tangency is stable with small perturbation. So what's the case for number four?